# A monad of tuples (monad, state)?

Tags: haskell, io, monads, state-monad

I am trying to write a Haskell "number-guessing" game program, using Monads, but I am stucked:
I tried the simple state monad:

```
data SM a = SMN (S -> (a, S))
instance Monad SM where
 SMN c1 >>= fc2 = SMN (\s0 -> let (r, s1) = c1 s0 in
                                let SMN c2 = fc2 r in
                                  c2 s1)
```

And I need to perform the IO tasks on the "IO-side" of the tuple (a, S), that is, I tried doing something like:

```
SMN c1 >>= fc2 = SMN (\s0 -> let (r, s1) = c1 s0 in
                               let SMN c2 = fc2 r in
                                 let (r1, s2) = c2 s1 in
                                   let r2 = r1 >>= (\_ -> r) in
                                     (r2, s2))
```

In short, the bind operator I would like to define is the same as the original state monad, except that we bind r1 and the constant function that takes an argument to r (so that the two actions are chained together). But the ghc tells me that a is a rigid type variable... What does that mean? I cannot use another bind operator inside one bind operator?
If so, then is there a way to implement such a bind operator? How?
As I am new to Haskell(I think I might have had a notational error concerning the function

```
\_ -> r
```

), any opinion and reference are welcomed, thanks in advance.
P.S. I used different notations for the data type SM and the type constructor SMN, so as to differentiate them.

Comment: The code is very confusing. Could you explain what it is that you're trying to do? It kind of sounds to me like you're trying to build something like `StateT s IO a`. You can find variants of that in `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict` and `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy`. But I can't say for sure because I don't understand your code.

Comment: @dfeuer I would liket to separate the monad action and the state record in the two parts of a tuple: (monad, state), so that I can call fst and snd when needed to separate them and perform some suitable actions. I don't know how to explain it explicitly, maybe after I complete the code I can show the usage of this monad, and then it will be clear what I am trying to build here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of `(>>=)` is:

```
Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Since you are writing an instance for `SM`, the type of bind in your instance is therefore

```
SM a -> (a -> SM b) -> SM b
```

Notice that both `a` and `b` are completely unrestricted type variables. That means whatever implementation you give *must* work no matter what types I choose to put in there. In particular, I could choose, say, `Int` for both `a` and `b`:

```
SM Int -> (Int -> SM Int) -> SM Int
```

And now it is clear why your implementation is no good: it will attempt to treat an `Int` as if it were a monadic action and call `(>>=)` on it.

If you want to be able to do monadic actions inside your bind, you will have to talk about the monad in your type somehow; for example, one standard way is to define

```
data SMT m a = SMT (S -> m (a, S))
```

and give an instance like:

```
instance Monad m => Monad (SMT m) where -- ...
```

The normal `SM` can then be recovered, if you like, by using the [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Identity.html) monad as the nested monad.

Comment: `S -> (m a, S)` doesn't work, it gives no way for the inner monad to affect the state. You need `S -> m (a, S)`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I don't want the inner monad to affect the state either, but still thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen That's certainly another choice; and it's more general. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: What I mean is that unless the inner monad is placed such that it can affect the state, I don't see how to make the combined type a monad. The problem is that with `bind :: (S -> (m a, S)) -> (a -> (S -> (m b, S)) -> (S -> (m b, S))` you have no chance to thread the states in such a way that you get the final `S` purely, because you only get it by using `a`, which you only get from inside the `m` monad.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks! I was going to comment about such a problem, and wondering if I should somehow define a function m a -> a. But how is the approach S -> m (a, S) going to solve this problem? Can I get a out of m (a, S)?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Ack, of course you are right. I will fix the answer in a moment.

Comment: @awllower The point is that you don't need to get the `a` out of the `m (a, S)` -- since the final action you need to return is also in the `m` monad.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I don't understand how exactly I can get this to work: now c1 s0 is of type m(a, S), and then I don't know what to apply fc2 to. Could you specify your solution to this problem? Thanks in any case for the attention.

Comment: @awllower It needs a slight change to your original code to use the inner monad bind instead of one of the `let`s: `SMT c1 >>= fc2 = SMT (\s0 -> c1 s0 >>= \(r, s1) -> let SMT c2 = fc2 r in c2 s1)`

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks for the great help you provide for a Haskell newbie like me! Thanks also go to DanielWagner. :)

Comment: Isn't this just `StateT S m a`?

Comment: @dfeuer I didn't know about the monad transformers, in particular, StateT. But still thanks for pointing this fact out!